# How do you build an array with certain elements from another array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

Given a one-dimensional array with n integers and a whole number A,
list how many elements are larger than A
and build an array with these elements.

I'm having problems with the last part.

Comment: The answer seems to be so simple that the question is confusing for me. So please explain why the answer is not "Find out the number (if necessary by going through the first array), create a corresponding `std::array`, search through first array and copy/reference into the second (if necessary by going through array again)." However, I also think that you should drop the "array" idea (doubly so if you are thinking of C-like arrays instead of `std::array`) and look into `std::vector` instead, for unpredictable sizes. (Downvote not by me.)

Comment: I am going to retract my close vote, if the question is confirmed (e.g., but not necessarily, via my answer being accepted....).

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This looks like a homework question, which (last time I checked) we explicitly do not allow on SO.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED I am not a fan of homework questions of the kind "Do this homework for me.", which I routinely close-vote. Homework questions which allow to assume that work has been spent (e.g. like here, where only the second half is asked about; giving benefit of the doubt) are subject to the compromise I linked inside my answer; in short "help, but do not solve completly). That compromise is the most official agreement I am aware of. Feel free to point me to a stricter and/or more official/more recent statement. Honest offer, no cynicism intended.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is almost already in the question
(giving it here, assuming that the question is really as simple as it confusingly seems to me):

- count the relevant elements, print/"list" that number
- create a new `std::array` of that size
- (consider asking whether using a `std::vector` is an option, it would allow doing this in a single pass)
- (explicitly do NOT attempt to use the non-C++ construct of C-style VLA, variable length arrays, like `std::cin>>n; int NewArray[n];`)
- go through the input array again and copy the relevant elements to the new array
- count indexes in both arrays separatly, because the index in the first array will soon be larger than the index into the new array

Note:
I intentionally do NOT provide code, because I feel that the compromise described here should be applied:  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create two arrays (if you can use **std::vectors**, i think they will work nicely in this scenario) - first one as a base, and the second one for storing values larger than A.

Get input of A and n.

Use a for loop to put n values into the base array.

Use a for loop to check if baseArray[i] is bigger than A, if true - put baseArray[i] into the second array (if youre using std::vectors do it by push_back()).

Display the number of values higher than A by secondArray.size().

Comment: Lets assume that OP really meant array when they wrote array. In that scope I do not see how your answer solves the problem caused by the difference between vector and array - that array size needs to be known beforehand, both C-style and C++-style. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Without using the std::vector:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  int A;
  int howManyBiggerThanA = 0;

  cin >> n;
  cin >> A;      //you haven't specified how the n and A are supposed to be implemented so ill assume its going to happen this way

  int *array = new int[n];    //creating an array with n integers
  array[0] = A;               //assigning A to the array as specified in the question - "and a whole number A"

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    array[i] = i;    //filling the array with n integers of value 1 to n-1 (u havent specified what values are supposed to be inside this array)
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (array[i] > A)
    {
      howManyBiggerThanA++;    //determining how many values are bigger than A
    }
  }

  int *arrayForBiggerThanA = new int[howManyBiggerThanA];    //creating an array for values that are bigger than A
  int assistant = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (array[i] > A)
    {
      arrayForBiggerThanA[assistant] = array[i];   //filling the second array with elements that are bigger than A
      assistant++;
    }
  }

  cout << "How many elements bigger than A: " << howManyBiggerThanA << endl;

  cout << "Values bigger than A: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < howManyBiggerThanA; i++)
    cout << arrayForBiggerThanA[i] << ", ";

  delete[] array;
  delete[] arrayForBiggerThanA;

  return 0;
}
```